# R data.table update a column of type list for a set of rows

Tags: r, data.table

Assume we have the following data.table:

```
> a <- data.table(id=(1:3), val=vector("list",length(3)))
> a$val <- list(c("a","b"),c("c","d","e"),c("f","e"))
> a
   id   val
1:  1   a,b
2:  2 c,d,e
3:  3   f,e
```

We now want to remove the element "e" from the column 'val' in rows with 'id' 2 and 3. 
I was able to achieve this with:

```
> for (x in c(2,3)) { 
  a[id==x, val := list(list(val[[1]][ val[[1]] != 'e']))]
  }
> a
   id val
1:  1 a,b
2:  2 c,d
3:  3   f
```

How can this be done with something like

```
a[id %in% c(2,3), ..] ?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function_remove<-function(x,y){
  if (y %in% c(2,3)){
    x<-x[[1]]
    list(x[x!="e"])
  } else{
    x
  }
}

a[,list(function_remove(val,id)),by=1:nrow(a)]
   nrow  V1
1:    1 a,b
2:    2 c,d
3:    3   f
```

Or you can do:

```
function_remove_1<-function(x){
  x[x!="e"]
}
a[id %in% c(2,3),]$val<-lapply(a[id %in% c(2,3),val],function_remove_1)
```

Finally (as suggested below) we can also update by reference:

```
a[id %in% c(1,2), val := lapply(val, function(x) x[x!="e"])]
```

Comment: thanks  for the idea of using lapply! I modified your second solution to use assignment by reference: 


`a[id %in% c(1,2), val := lapply(val, function(x) x[x!="e"])]`

would you like to include it in your answer?

Comment: awesome. Thanks again!